# Return inline JSON from endpoint

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Mostly this is about just sending hard coded JSON from Web API method back to a caller app ( happens to be React). My current action looks something like the following:

```
[Route("members/{memberId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Members(string memberId) 
{
   //  {
   //       "SecA4": ["Asian"]
   //  }

   // ??  string json = "{ \"SecA4\": [\"Asian\"] }";   //??

   return OK() // need to place JSON in the OK() method. but how should it be done?
}
```

So currently I am able to load from a file into a survey engine a file that looks like that.  Thus I load from a .json file.

```
{
 "SecA4": ["Asian"]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to return json from a file, or do you want to return just Json?

Comment: not from a file.   hard coded in the csharp code  seems i have need " for valid json , so i am having to manually put in backslashes for the quotes,  thus  `string json = "{ \"SecA4\": [\"Asian\"] }";`  that returns in postman..    Eventually I will need to do sql queries and pull...  i just needed to start on it for POC

Comment: Why do you want to hardcode the JSON?

Comment: POC (proof of concept ) as i'm mostly working on React UI - needed to be sure that the mapping of data works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather then a hard-coded string I would use an object rather, which would be done something like the following

```cs
object someObject = new
{
    SecA4 = "Asian"
};
```

You can create this pretty much the same way as you would do with Json.

Now we are just returning the newly created object and converting it into Json.

```cs
return Json(someObject, new JsonSerializerSettings() { Formatting = Formatting.None });
```

Where in the `JsonSerializerSettings` you can tell Newtonsoft.Json to no use any formatting e.g. new lines, spaces and so on.